# Combining the caption and fltpage package when using twopage setting in book class

Tags: captions, double-sided

I have run into a strange problem when using the `caption` package and the `fltpage` package in the `book` documentclass with the `twoside` setting.
After eliminating all kinds of variable it turned out that what is given below is the true MWE for the problem. I assume I'm doing something wrong as I'm relatively new to LaTeX and probably missed something in the documentation of the `caption` package.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[leftFloats, CaptionAfterwards]{fltpage}

\begin{document}

\captionsetup[FPfigure]{format=hang, font=small, labelfont=bf}

\begin{FPfigure}
    \fbox{\rule[-10cm]{0pt}{\textheight}Frame ... page.\hspace{5cm}}
    \caption{A caption alone ... figure without a caption!}
\end{FPfigure}

\end{document}
```

If the option `twoside` is removed than it will produced the desired layout for the caption. But with it I get the following errors:

> 7x Illegal parameter number in definition of \AP@ \end{FPfigure}
>   Undefined control sequence \end{document}   Environment undefined.
>   Undefined control sequence \end{document}   Package caption Error: No
>   float type '' defined   29x Missing \endcsname inserted   Reference
>   `FPfigure-1-pos' on page 1 undefined on input line 10.

If the `fltpage` environment is not used (just a normal figure) then also no errors are given and the correct layout is produced.
I'm working on a Windows system using MiKTeX 2.9

As this is for my thesis I really need the `twoside` option. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I must say that I didn't try other classes.

Comment: Can you use `rightFloats` instead of `leftFloats`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Preferably not as that would result requiring the reader to flip the page to see the figure legend if I'm not mistaken. In addition I just tested it, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: I just realised that the `book` class as a default uses the `twoside` option (http://texblog.org/2007/07/09/documentclassbook-report-article-or-letter/) so there is no real need to define it as such. I don't have access to LaTeX at the moment but will test if the layout changes for my master document (on the MWE I did not notice this).

Comment: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve the "problem" as it turned out not to be problem at all.

As already stated in the question, removing the `twoside` option resulted in the MWE functioning again. At first I didn't realise this, but as the `book` documentclass has by *default* the layout set as two-sided! So including it doesn't add anything, but more importantly, removing the statement doesn't change anything either!

In essence, the fix in the question was already the answer, but it is a mystery why the explicit statement of a default setting would result in these error messages.

I then did some further testing with classes that do not as a default have the `twoside` option enabled such as the `article` class. Without any statement (so default, `oneside`) the effect is as desired and doesn't give any error messages. However, when the option `twoside` is passed it again results in errors.

In summary, it would seem that the `fltpage` and `caption` packages are incompatible when used in a documentclass that:
a. has not, by default, a `twoside` layout; and a `twoside` layout is required and therefore passed as an option; or
b. has by default a `twoside` layout but this is also given as a statement when devining the documentclass.

My question related to the second option and is therefore answered, remove the optional mentioning of the `twoside` option. The issue remains for people wanting to use it in other documentclasses such as `article`, in combination with `twoside` layout.

Comment: As I'm new to the site as a question asker/answerer I don't know what to do now. Rephrase the original question so that it now is about the `article` documentclass? Or mark it as "answered" and leave it at that? It would be good if some senior people could comment on this.

Comment: In addition, it would seem to me that this is really a bug in either of the two macro's. Because the fltpage packages is not actively maintained (and is in fact still a beta) I will point the maintainer of `caption` to this question, and hope for other users that it issue is related to that package.

Comment: I'd say you've answered your own question here: please mark with the 'checkmark' (when you can).

Comment: The example document does not compile either if the `caption` package isn't used. It seems that the `fltpage` package itself does not like `twoside` combined with either `leftFloats` or `CaptionAfterwards` (or both). So it seems this is a bug in `fltpage`.